# Making a reusable angular2 component that can be used anywhere on the a site

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Use Case: When making asynchronous calls, I want to show some sort of a processing screen so that end users knows something is happening rather than just staring at the screen. Since I have multiple places throughout the site where I want to use this, I figured making it a component at the "global" level is the best approach.

Problem: Being slightly new to angular2, I'm not getting if this is a problem of it being outside the directory in which the main component exists and the OverlayComponent being in another location or if I'm just all together doing it wrong. I can get the component to work fine but I need to be able to call functions to hide/destroy the component and also display the component. I have tried making it a service but that didn't get me any further so I'm back to square one. Essentially my question revolves around building a reusable component that has methods to hide/show itself when invoked from whatever component it's being called from.

Below is my current code:

Assume OverlayComponent.html is at /public/app/templates/mysite.overlay.component.html

Assume OverlayComponent.ts is at /public/app/ts/app.mysite.overlay.component

Assume mysite.tracker.component is at \public\app\ts\pages\Tracker\mysite.tracker.component.ts

**OverlayComponent.html**

```
<div class="overlay-component-container">
    <div class="overlay-component" (overlay)="onShowOverlay($event)">
        <div>{{processingMessage}}</div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OverlayComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

    selector: 'overlay-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/mysite.overlay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['public/app/scss/overlay.css']
})

export class OverlayComponent {

    onShowOverlay(e) {
        $('.overlay-component').fadeIn(1000);
    }

    hideOverlay(e) {
        $('.overlay-component').fadeOut(1000);
    }

}
```

**TrackerComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { TrackerService } from './Tracker.service';
import { MenuCollection } from "./MenuCollection";
import { Menu } from "./Menu";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'tracker-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/pages/tracker/mysite.tracker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../../scss/pages/racker/tracker.css'],
    providers: [TrackerService]
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    MenuCollection: MenuCollection;

    @Output()
    overlay: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private http: Http, private TrackerService: TrackerService) {
        let c = confirm("test");
        if (c) {
            this.onShowOverlay();
        }
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.MenuCollection = new MenuCollection();
        this.MenuCollection.activeMenu = new Menu('Active Menu', []);
        this.TrackerService.getTrackerData().then(Tracker => {
            this.MenuCollection = Tracker;
            this.MenuCollection.activeMenu = this.MenuCollection.liveMenu;
            console.log(this.MenuCollection);

        },
        error => {
            alert('error');
        })
    }

    onShowOverlay() { //This doesn't seem to 'emit' and trigger my overlay function
        this.overlay.emit('test');
    }


}
```

At a high level, all I'm wanting to do is invoke a components function from another component. Thanks in advance for any helpful input

Comment: Believe the service is the way to go that along with a component that uses the service and registers itself with the service so it can "tell" the component to change.  Will give this a go if no answer is posted in a while.

Comment: From what I understand about angular services (in both angular1 and 2), it's what I need. However, when I implemented it, i kept getting errors about it not finding components or directives not being a property of Component. If you can spin up a JS fiddle or code snippet on how to accomplish calling a service from any component and that service invoking code from another component (regardless of where it's at in the folder structure) that would solve my problem. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't care if it aligns with what I have above as I realize that it's easier to create your own basic example than try and get mine working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@ContentChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChild-decorator.html) annotation to accomplish this:

```
import { Component, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

class ChildComponent {
  // Implementation
}

// this component's template has an instance of ChildComponent
class ParentComponent {
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Do stuff with this.child
  }
}
```

For more examples, check out the [`@ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html) documentation.